# Magento 2 - How to get quote shipping method in knockout js?

Tags: magento2, javascript, shipping-methods, knockoutjs

In Magento 2 I try to get shipping method in this js file : `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html`

I try this :

```
quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'];
```

And I have this error  :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method_code' of null
```

But when I `console.log(quote);` I can see shippingMethod method code exist:
[image]

Do you have any idea how can I get shipping method attributes here ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

My goal is to change data-bind in this file : `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html`

```
<fieldset class="fieldset" data-bind="visible: !isAddressDetailsVisible()">
```

In order that `isAddressDetailsVisible()` method return false if current shipping method is "colissimo pickup".

Comment: What do you see if you add console.log(quote.shippingMethod())?

Comment: @BenCrook I see "null"

Comment: It sounds like your code is running before the shipping method is set (in code, not necessarily by the user). Have you tried subscribing to `quote.shippingMethod` then running your code when it updates? Off the top of my head I think it would be `quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(function(value) { console.log(value); })`

Comment: Thanks it seems to work (I had to add code in initObservable function). But I have to refresh page, it doesn't work on the first page load. Do you know why ?

Comment: It still sounds like your code is running before the value is populated, once the user loads the page that value gets populated (possibly server side and then passed to the component). It's hard to say without being able to debug.

Comment: Do you know how to reload billing-address template in js ? In order to simulate reload page in checkout payment step

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple way:

```
quote.shippingMethod().method_code
```

Where **quote** is ***'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'***

Avoiding js error, try the following way:

```
if (quote.shippingMethod() != undefined) {
    quote.shippingMethod().method_code
}
```

**[Update]**

Add the following code in your js class inside **initialize** method. Ex. view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js **initialize**

```
quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(function (method) {
    if (method.method_code == 'your_method_code') {
        this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
    }
}, this);
```

Comment: Thanks but I have this error : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method_code' of null.
You can see my edit I add more information about what I want.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks it seems to work (I had to add code not in initialize but in initObservable function). But I have to refresh page, it doesn't work on the first page load. Do you know why ?

Comment: What is the solution ?